# Como acceder a los elementos de una clase vector

Tags: java, array

Estoy creando un programa el cual permite que los usuarios se registren mediante el ingreso de su nombre, apellido, cedula, fecha de nacimiento. Esta información se guarda en un vector que utiliza de base una plantilla de una clase Persona que cree. El problema que tengo es quiero crear una opcion que le permita al usuario solo consultar su fecha de nacimiento. No se como acceder solamente a esa información sin mostrar (como me ocurre) toda la información que este en la posición de (i) en el vector.

Clase principal

```
package excepciones.definitivo;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class ExcepcionesDefinitivo{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Vector usuarios = new Vector(5,2);
        String nombre;
        String apellido;
        int dia,mes,anio,respuesta,cedula,respuesta2,respuesta3;
        
        
        do{
            
            System.out.println("Bienvenido" + "\n" + "ingrese la opcion que desea");
            System.out.println("1 = Ingresar nuevo usuario");
            System.out.println("2 = Mostrar usuarios");
            System.out.println("3 = Mostrar algun usuario en especifico");
            System.out.println("4 = Mostrar fecha de algun usuario en especifico");
            System.out.println("5 = Salir");
            respuesta = entrada.nextInt();
            switch(respuesta){
                
                case 1:
            System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
            nombre = entrada.next();
        
            System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido");
            apellido = entrada.next();
            
            System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula");
            cedula = entrada.nextInt();
        
            System.out.println("Ingrese su dia de nacimiento");
            dia = entrada.nextInt();
        
            System.out.println("Ingrese su mes de nacimiento");
            mes = entrada.nextInt();
        
            System.out.println("Ingrese su anio de nacimiento");
            anio = entrada.nextInt();
            
            usuarios.add(new Persona(nombre,apellido,cedula,dia,mes,anio));break;
            
                case 2: 
                for(int i=0; i<usuarios.size();i++){
                        System.out.println("Usuario "+(i+1));
                        System.out.println(usuarios.elementAt(i).toString());
                    }break;
            
                case 3:
                       System.out.println("Ingrese el numero del usuario que desea saber");
                       respuesta2 = entrada.nextInt();
                       
                       respuesta2 = respuesta2 - 1;
                       System.out.println(usuarios.elementAt(respuesta2));break;
                       
                case 4: 
                    
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero del usuario del cual desea saber la fecha");
                    respuesta3 = entrada.nextInt();
                    respuesta3 = respuesta3 - 1;
                    System.out.println(usuarios.elementAt(respuesta3));
                    
                    
                    
            }}while(respuesta!=5);
        
    }
    
}
```

clase Persona

```
package excepciones.definitivo;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Persona {
    
    // atributos
    
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    int dia,mes,anio,cedula;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public int getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(int cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }
    
    // metodos

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido,int cedula, int dia, int mes, int anio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

   
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Nombre: " + nombre + "\n" + 
                "Apellido: " + apellido + "\n" + 
                "Cedula: " + cedula + "\n" +
                "Fecha de nacimiento: " + dia +"/"+ mes +"/"+ anio;
                
    }

    
 
    public String fecha(){
        return "Fecha de nacimiento: " + dia +"/"+ mes +"/" + anio;
    }
    
    
}
```

Lo que ocurre cuando ejecuto el programa

```
1 = Ingresar nuevo usuario
2 = Mostrar usuarios
3 = Mostrar algun usuario en especifico
4 = Mostrar fecha de algun usuario en especifico
5 = Salir
1
Ingrese su nombre
Andres
Ingrese su apellido
Moreno
Ingrese su cedula
1021564986
Ingrese su dia de nacimiento
25
Ingrese su mes de nacimiento
05
Ingrese su anio de nacimiento
1999
Bienvenido
ingrese la opcion que desea
1 = Ingresar nuevo usuario
2 = Mostrar usuarios
3 = Mostrar algun usuario en especifico
4 = Mostrar fecha de algun usuario en especifico
5 = Salir
4
Ingrese el numero del usuario del cual desea saber la fecha
1
Nombre: Andres
Apellido: Moreno
Cedula: 1021564986
Fecha de nacimiento: 25/5/1999
Bienvenido
```

Comment: ya intentaste con `usuarios.elementAt(respuesta3).getCedula()`?

Comment: Es que la información que quiero esta almacenada en fecha de nacimiento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tendrías que realizar un `cast` del objeto obtenido con `get` y asi poder hacer uso de tu método fecha

```
case 4:
      System.out.println("Ingrese el numero del usuario del cual desea saber la fecha");
      respuesta3 = entrada.nextInt();
      respuesta3 = respuesta3 - 1;
      System.out.println(((Persona)usuarios.get(respuesta3)).fecha ()+"\n");
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! :D